# column slots in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset `x` with 350m rows and 4 columns. When joining two columns from a dataset `i` of 13m rows and 19 columns, I encounter the following error:

```
Internal logical error. DT passed to assign has not been allocated enough column slots. l=4, tl=4, adding 1
```

I have checked [Not Enough Columns Slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551967/not-enough-columns-slots) but there the problem appears to be in the number of columns. Since I have only a few, I would be surprised if this was the issue.

Also, I found https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1830, where the error is related to "column slots", but I do not understand what they are. When checking truelength, I obtain

```
> truelength(x)
[1] 0
> truelength(i)
[1] 0
```

My understanding is that setting, for example, `alloc.col(x,32)` or `alloc.col(i,32)`, or both could solve the issue. However, I don`t understand what this does and and what the issue is. Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: Are you familiar with the note about "Reading data.table from RDS or RData file" in `vignette("datatable-faq")`? In my experience truelength 0 comes from loaded tables. Of course `?alloc.col` might be a place to look if you want to know what it does

Comment: Thanks, I will check that FAQ. I did read the documentation on these functions, but I just don't understand what these slots are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of what makes `data.table` so efficient is it tries to be smart about memory usage (whereas `base` `data.frames` tend to end up getting copied left and right in regular usage, e.g., setting `names(DF) = col_names` *can actually copy all of `DF`* despite only manipulating an attribute of the object).

Part of this, in turn, is that a `data.table` is always allocated a certain size in memory to allow for adding/subtracting column *pointers* more fluidly (from a memory perspective).

So, while actual *columns* take memory *greedily* (when they're created, sufficient memory is claimed to store the `nrow(DT)`-size vector), the column *pointers*, which store addresses where to find the actual data (you can think of this ~like~ column names, if you don't know the grittier details of pointers), have a fixed memory slot upon creation.

`alloc.col` forces the column pointer address reserve process; this is most commonly used in two cases:

1. Your data needs a lot of columns (by default, room is allocated for 1024 pointers more than there are columns at definition)
2. You've loaded your data from RDS (since `readRDS`/`load` don't know to allocate this memory for a `data.table` upon loading, we have to trigger this ourselves)

I assume Frank is right and that you're experiencing the latter. See `?alloc.col` for some more details, but in most cases, you should just run `alloc.col(x)` and `alloc.col(i)` -- except for highly constrained machines, allocating 1024 column *pointers* requires relatively little memory, so you shouldn't spend to much effort skimping and trying to figure out the right quantity.